# What function $f(x)$ such $f(x)f(1/x)=x^{10}$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Give an example any function such
$$f(x)f(1/x)=x^{10}$$

I think the polynomials function can't exist? so we can find other form such this?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $g(x)=f(x)f(1/x)$ then $g(x)=g(1/x)$.

Comment: This hint it is clear,but following can find?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$f(x)f(1/x)=x^k$$

But by letting $x\mapsto1/x$, we get

$$f(1/x)f(x)=1/x^k=x^k$$

Which can only be true at $x=\pm1$, thus $f(x)$ is only defined at $x=\pm1$.

Comment: $x$ can complex

Comment: If you're willing to include complex numbers, then yes, $f(x)$ is defined at $20$ different points. But $f(x)$ is still not continuous like you may have wanted.

Comment: @communnites most functional equations are considered over $\mathbb R$ unless specified :-)

Comment: @communnities: If you are using $x$ as your variable your are implicitly implying that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as Simply Beautiful Art already said.